# apex class trace problem: start date and end date cannot configure

Tags: apex, debugging, stacktrace

I want to trace an apex class running process then setup as following:

1. click Developer console->debug->change log levels
2. In the section "class and trigger trace overrides", I choose related apex class, afterward, I set the Start date, end date and debug level.
3. click done

but always got two abnormal or error setting as following:

a.) start date and end date always auto change to other time

b.) or always get this error message

[image]

anyone can help?

**New update:**
Here is example:

1. I want to set start date as 2PM and end date as 6PM
   [image]
2. after I set, I just click any place in the UI then date changed to 2AM to 2PM
   [image]
3. Then, I click done. I got error message
   [image]
4. I reopen panel again, then I saw date change again. 10PM to 2AM
   [image]

**New Update (10-5-2016):**
I checked, My time zone and locale of my computer and Salesforce account are same, here is screenshot:

**Salesforce**
[image]

**My Computer**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: what are the dates you are selecting ? for me error is self explanatory

Comment: Hi @Himanshu, I already update at the top

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your SFDC User profile Timezone is different from your computer timezone. You select the date as per your system time and you get this error. Make them in sync and after that select time in developer console.

SFDC display time as per your SFDC timezone settings.

Comment: Hi @Himanshu, I already update at the top

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to click on the Expiration column and select the time again. It seems that it remains expired unless you check this field again.
[image]